# Obfuscation of Spring Boot modules

Tags: java, spring, proguard, obfuscation

I wonder, is there a decent approach to obfuscate spring boot module's code?
Tried to use Pro Guard, but faced with need of spring to keep some fields names to be untouched in runtime (DTO for (de)serialization,  DO entities for db columns linking, and so on).

Comment: Where are you publishing the compiled code that this is relevant?

Comment: The point is, I need to provide some organization with my code for demo usage.
And they'll have all the artifacts. So, I wan't to secure it somehow. To not let them just decompile and use it in future.

Comment: ...*want to secure....

Comment: There used to be a gcc gcj technology to transform bytecode to binaries, but its not supported anymore.

Comment: I will not completely blame proGuard, I have obfuscate spring boot application with proguard and maven, and learned few things, I agree spring uses reflection but as long as you are using qualifier and explicit bean names  it will work like a charm, serialization is still a concern but just think what do you lose if you don't obfuscate all DTOs because DTO contains nothing which you need to protect

Answer (score 1):

One good possibility is too use [ProGuard](https://medium.com/@ijayakantha/obfuscate-spring-boot-2-applications-with-proguard-a8a76586b11f#:%7E:text=In%20software%20development%2C%20obfuscation%20is,hacker%20but%20remains%20fully%20functional.), it's is an open source most popular optimizer and obfuscator for Java byte code, quit simple to configure it, Create a file named “proguard.cfg” at the root level as your pom is located and add htis two plugin to you pom plugins.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<plugins>
<plugin>       
<groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>       
<artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>       <version>2.3.1</version>       
<executions>          
<execution>             
<phase>package</phase>             
<goals>                
<goal>proguard</goal>             
</goals>          
</execution>       
</executions>       
<configuration>          
<proguardVersion>6.0.3</proguardVersion>          <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>          <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>          <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>          <proguardInclude>${project.basedir}/proguard.cfg</proguardInclude>          <libs>             
<lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>             <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>             <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>          
</libs>       
</configuration>       
<dependencies>          
<dependency>             
<groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>             
<artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>             <version>6.0.3</version>          
</dependency>       
</dependencies>
</plugin>    
<plugin>       
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>       <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>       
<executions>          
<execution>             
<goals>                
<goal>repackage</goal>             
</goals>             
<configuration>                <mainClass>com.jayk.springboot.proguard.obfuscationdemo.ObfuscationDemoApplication</mainClass>             
</configuration>          
</execution>       
</executions>    
</plugin> 
</plugins>
```

then add below configuration in your proguard.cfg

```
-target 1.8 ##Specify the java version number
-dontshrink ##Default is enabled, here the shrink is turned off, that is, the unused classes/members are not deleted.
-dontoptimize ##Default is enabled, here to turn off bytecode level optimization
-useuniqueclassmembernames ## Take a unique strategy for confusing the naming of class members
-adaptclassstrings ## After confusing the class name, replace it with a place like Class.forName('className')
-dontnote
-ignorewarnings ## warnings are ignored
-dontwarn
-keep public class * extends org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
-keepdirectories ## Keep the package structure
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static void main(java.lang.String[]);} ##Maintain the class of the main method and its method name
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }  ##Reserving enumeration members and methods
-keepclassmembers class * {
     @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *;
     @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier *;
     @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
     @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required *;
     @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean *;
     @org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary *;
     @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties *;
     @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties *;
     @javax.inject.Inject *;
     @javax.annotation.PostConstruct *;
     @javax.annotation.PreDestroy *;
}
-keep @org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching class *
-keep @org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration class *
-keep @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties class *
-keep @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication class *
-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepdirectories com.jayk.springboot.proguard.obfuscationdemo
-keepdirectories org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure
## Do not change names of the getters and setter, if you remove this ##thymeleaf unable to find the getter and setter i.e: ##${greetingDTO.message}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    *** get*();
    void set*(***);
}
-keepclassmembernames class * {
     java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
     java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
     public static **[] values();
     public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
     public static ** fromValue(java.lang.String);
}
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembernames public class com.test.blah.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
     static final long serialVersionUID;
     private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
     !static !transient <fields>;
     !private <fields>;
     !private <methods>;
     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
     java.lang.Object writeReplace();
     java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
     @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired <fields>;
     @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired <methods>;
     @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize <methods>;
}
```

find more example in [here](https://github.com/devslm/proguard-spring-boot-example) .

Comment: Thanks for answer! 
Pro Guard is nor really suitable here as I mentioned before:
spring deals a lot with reflection, so code units must stay unmodified.